# How to dynamically get java string constants in android?

Tags: java, android

I have DTO classes like this Production_Dispatch_Res_DTO and V_DL_INDEX_ENTRY_ALL_DATA.

the variables that are declared in the DTO classes will be send by the webservice.

To receive the data I have create object to the Production_Dispatch_Res_DTO class in my Activity.

and the object for the DTO class is `assetres`. I wanted to access all strings in assetres and store them in a string array.

for that I have tried like this.

```
for(int i =0; i< assetres.V_DL_INDEX_ENTRY_ALL_DATA.size;i++){
       but size is not available here.

}
```

I need to generate a loop and it will rotate until the size of V_DL_INDEX_ENTRY_ALL_DATA and store them in a String array.

```
public class Production_Dispatch_Res_DTO {
public V_DL_INDEX_ENTRY_ALL_DATA V_DL_INDEX_ENTRY_ALL_DATA;
public String Product_Name;
public String PROD_MFG_DATE;
}

public class V_DL_INDEX_ENTRY_ALL_DATA {
public String DLSNO ;
public long DIGITALCNT;
public long ANALOGCNT;
public String CUSTOMERNAME;
public String SALEORDERREFNAME;
public String VERSIONCONTROLNO;
public String FIRMWAREVERSIONNO;
public String EFF_820M;
public long EFF_827_CARDCNT;
public String EFF_827;
public String EFF_715M;
public String EFF_1295;
public String EFF_1297;
public String EFF_824M;
public String EFF_823M ;
public String EFF_822M ;
public long EFF_1390A_CARDCNT;
public String EFF_1390A;
public long EFF_1390B_CARDCNT;
public String EFF_1390B;
public long EFF_1390C_CARDCNT ;
public String EFF_1390C ;
public long EFF_1390D_CARDCNT ;
public String EFF_1390D ;
public long EFF_828_CARDCNT ;
public String EFF_828;
public long EFF_721_CARDCNT ;
public String EFF_721;
public long EFF_508M4_CARDCNT ;
public String EFF_508M4 ;
public long EFF_1890_CARDCNT;
public String EFF_1890;
public String EFF_1296 ;
public String EFF_887 ;
public String EFF_516M2 ;
public String EFF_850 ;
public String EFF_1000M2 ;
public long EFF_1015M2_CARDCNT;
public String EFF_1015M2;
public String ISOLATIONBOX ;
public long ISOLATIONBOX_SNO ;
public long CHARGER_CNT;
public String CHARGER ;
public String EFF_712M ;
public String EFF_712M_1;
public String EFF_712M_2 ;
public String EFF_712M_3 ;
public String EFF_712M_4;
public String EFF_712M_5;
public String EFF_712M_6;
public String EFF_712M_7;
/*DateTime ENTRYDATETIME ;
DateTime STARTTIME;*/
}
 strEFF_827 = assetRes.V_DL_INDEX_ENTRY_ALL_DATA.EFF_827;
    strEFF_820M = assetRes.V_DL_INDEX_ENTRY_ALL_DATA.EFF_820M;
    strEFF_715M = assetRes.V_DL_INDEX_ENTRY_ALL_DATA.EFF_715M;
    strEFF_1295 = assetRes.V_DL_INDEX_ENTRY_ALL_DATA.EFF_1295;
    strEFF_1297 = assetRes.V_DL_INDEX_ENTRY_ALL_DATA.EFF_1297;
    strEFF_824M = assetRes.V_DL_INDEX_ENTRY_ALL_DATA.EFF_824M;
    strEFF_823M = assetRes.V_DL_INDEX_ENTRY_ALL_DATA.EFF_823M;
    strEFF_822M = assetRes.V_DL_INDEX_ENTRY_ALL_DATA.EFF_822M;
    strEFF_1390A = assetRes.V_DL_INDEX_ENTRY_ALL_DATA.EFF_1390A;
    strEFF_1390B = assetRes.V_DL_INDEX_ENTRY_ALL_DATA.EFF_1390B;
    strEFF_1390C = assetRes.V_DL_INDEX_ENTRY_ALL_DATA.EFF_1390C;
    strEFF_1390D = assetRes.V_DL_INDEX_ENTRY_ALL_DATA.EFF_1390D;
    strEFF_828 = assetRes.V_DL_INDEX_ENTRY_ALL_DATA.EFF_828;
    strEFF_721 = assetRes.V_DL_INDEX_ENTRY_ALL_DATA.EFF_721;
    strEFF_508M4 = assetRes.V_DL_INDEX_ENTRY_ALL_DATA.EFF_508M4;
    strEFF_1890 = assetRes.V_DL_INDEX_ENTRY_ALL_DATA.EFF_1890;
    strEFF_1296 = assetRes.V_DL_INDEX_ENTRY_ALL_DATA.EFF_1296;
    strEFF_887 = assetRes.V_DL_INDEX_ENTRY_ALL_DATA.EFF_887;
    strEFF_516M2 = assetRes.V_DL_INDEX_ENTRY_ALL_DATA.EFF_516M2;
    strEFF_850 = assetRes.V_DL_INDEX_ENTRY_ALL_DATA.EFF_850;
    strEFF_1000M2 = assetRes.V_DL_INDEX_ENTRY_ALL_DATA.EFF_1000M2;
    strEFF_1015M2 = assetRes.V_DL_INDEX_ENTRY_ALL_DATA.EFF_1015M2;
    strEFF_712M = assetRes.V_DL_INDEX_ENTRY_ALL_DATA.EFF_712M;
    strEFF_712M_1 = assetRes.V_DL_INDEX_ENTRY_ALL_DATA.EFF_712M_1;
    strEFF_712M_2=assetRes.V_DL_INDEX_ENTRY_ALL_DATA.EFF_712M_2;
    strEFF_712M_3=assetRes.V_DL_INDEX_ENTRY_ALL_DATA.EFF_712M_3;
    strEFF_712M_4=assetRes.V_DL_INDEX_ENTRY_ALL_DATA.EFF_712M_4;
    strEFF_712M_5=assetRes.V_DL_INDEX_ENTRY_ALL_DATA.EFF_712M_5;
    strEFF_712M_6=assetRes.V_DL_INDEX_ENTRY_ALL_DATA.EFF_712M_6;
    strEFF_712M_7=assetRes.V_DL_INDEX_ENTRY_ALL_DATA.EFF_712M_7;
    strCHARGER=assetRes.V_DL_INDEX_ENTRY_ALL_DATA.CHARGER;
```

[image: Data is coming like this in JSon format from webserver]

I have hardcoded like this. But I need to add dynamically.

I need to generate a loop and it will rotate until the size of V_DL_INDEX_ENTRY_ALL_DATA and store in a String array.

How to do it.

Comment: I think you have to use `Gson Library` for parse server json result. and you can store in `hashMap` and iterate over loop.

Comment: can u elaborate your suggestion or else please suggest me the example links.@skpanchal

Comment: `the size of V_DL_INDEX_ENTRY_ALL_DATA` what does that mean?

Answer (score 0):

1. Generate setter, getters for V_DL_INDEX_ENTRY_ALL_DATA.
2. Take an array list of type V_DL_INDEX_ENTRY_ALL_DATA in

like:

```
List<V_DL_INDEX_ENTRY_ALL_DATA> allDataList = new ArrayList<>();
```

3. Set all values to V_DL_INDEX_ENTRY_ALL_DATA in for loop

like:

```
for(int i = 0; i < webServiceData.size(); i++) {
  V_DL_INDEX_ENTRY_ALL_DATA  allData = new V_DL_INDEX_ENTRY_ALL_DATA();
  allData.setDLSNO("someNumber");
  allData.setDIGITALCNT(123l);
  //-----
  //-----
  //----- // TODO add all data like this

  allDataList.add(allData);
}
```